# Is there anything in nhibernate that lets me get the list of mapped classes that refer some other class?

Tags: nhibernate

Is there some feature in nhibernate that goes through all the mapping files and can get me a list of class names that refer to (many to one) another class?

It would be quite handy, if I could do this, then I could run some queries to tell the user exactly why they're not allowed to delete certain values, instead of throwing a gross looking foreign key violation message...

Thanks

Isaac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An extremely simplified approach:

```
foreach (var classMetadata in sessionFactory.GetAllClassMetadata())
    foreach (propertyType in classMetadata.PropertyTypes)
        if (propertyType.IsEntityType)
            //this is a foreign key
```

Then you have `sessionFactory.GetAllCollectionMetadata()`, etc.

This should get you started.

Comment: been working on this one a couple hours now, and it seems to be the right path. Just a few little kinks to work out. Thanks Diego!